# XPATH and XMLStarlet

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

I am struggling now with the following task. I am trying to remove empty XML entry with use of XMLStarlet.

What I trying is to use this XPATH:

```
//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())='')]
```

I've tested it on http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and it works as expected. Mated together with XMLStarlet doesn't work:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())='')]'
```

What could be the reason of that?

Comment: In what way it didn't work? Please provide sample XML to test...

Answer (score 2):

Try to use quotes in double quotes or vice versa.

For your example:

```shell
xmlstarlet ed -d '//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())="")]'
```

or

```shell
xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[not(./*) and (not(./text()) or normalize-space(./text())='')]"
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked it and it works as expected. Many thanks.